# onActivity result is never called

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult

I want to get data back from the second Activity, but the onActivityResult never gets called. I've tried all the possible solutions i've seen on stackoverflow but none of them worked.
I checked the AndroidManifest and i don't have the

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

This is a part of the code of MainActivity (extends from AppCompatActivity):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Alarm> alarms = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    AlarmAdapter alarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(MainActivity.this, alarms);
    Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MapsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,2);
        }
    });
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.alarmList);
    listView.setAdapter(alarmAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(requestCode == 2){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            AlarmAdapter alarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(MainActivity.this, alarms);
            Alarm newAlarm3 = new Alarm("Nueva", data.getExtras().getDouble("lat"), data.getExtras().getDouble("lng"));
            alarmAdapter.add(newAlarm3);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cancel",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fuera",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

And this is (part of) the code of the second Activity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    //Intent intent = getIntent();
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Button btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    Button btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent returnData = new Intent();
            returnData.putExtra("lat", lat);
            returnData.putExtra("lng",lng);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnData);
            finish();
        }
    });

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How are you determining that `onActivityResult()` isn't being called? If you're relying on those `Toast`s, I would point out that you're missing the call to `show()` on all of them.

Comment: Wow, I'm so stupid, the problem wasn't the onActivityResult (I determined that because the toast were not showing and the object was not being added to the list), apparently the problem is the addition of the object to the list. Thank you very much for the fast answer and sorry for my stupidity xD

Comment: Ok, everything working now, i just forgot to add the listview on the onActivityResult. I should sleep a bit more when i want to code. Thanks.